# generating list of lists with linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

i have a query which its result is as follow:

```
----------------------------
sid    name    count
----------------------------
1021   o        1
1021   t        5
1022   t        10
1023   h        14
```

my desired result should be list which first element is sid(which is unique) and second element should be a list of name and count

something like this:

```
[1021, [(o,1), (t,5)]]; [1022, (t,10)]
```

i have no idea what to do, maybe i can use dictionary but i cant distinguish unique sids.
can some one give me a hint? tnx in advanced

Comment: Sounds like you want `ToLookup`...

Comment: maybe use `GroupBy`?

Comment: @ric the result of my first query which is shown in that table is result of group by on two colomns of sid and name

Comment: I meant use Linq GroupBy: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb534501(v=vs.90).aspx, the way @Enigmativity has done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var source = new []
{
    new { sid = 1021, name = "o", count = 1, },
    new { sid = 1021, name = "t", count = 5, },
    new { sid = 1022, name = "t", count = 10, },
    new { sid = 1023, name = "h", count = 14, },
};

var query =
    from x in source
    group new { x.name, x.count } by x.sid;
```

That gives me this:

[image: query]

If you specifically wanted that textual output then this would work:

```
var query =
    String.Join("; ",
        from x in source
        group new { x.name, x.count } by x.sid into gxs
        select String.Format("[{0}, [{1}]]", gxs.Key, String.Join(", ",
            gxs.Select(gx => String.Format("({0},{1})", gx.name, gx.count)))));
```

Then I get:

```
[1021, [(o,1), (t,5)]]; [1022, [(t,10)]]; [1023, [(h,14)]]
```

Comment: would you please give me lambda expression for var query =
    from x in source
    group new { x.name, x.count } by x.sid;

Comment: @joe - `source.GroupBy(x => x.sid, x => new { x.name, x.count })`